# Node JS mysql returning wrong value for 1 column in database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to get some records from my database in node JS with the MYSQL library but i am getting the wrong value for the column pid. It returns 76561198056610560 every time for all records even when the value of that column is something else.

**This is what my table looks like:**

```
did int(10) unsigned        NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
pid bigint(20) unsigned     NO  MUL NULL    
oid int(10) unsigned        NO      NULL    
secretcode  varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
reward  int(10) unsigned    NO      NULL    
status  tinyint(1)          NO      NULL    
offersent   tinyint(1)      NO      NULL    
created_at  timestamp       NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
updated_at  timestamp       NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

**Contents of the table:**

```
1   76561198056610558   0   @JAMIE@SECRET1  100 0   0   2016-01-21 10:09:30 0000-00-00 00:00:00
2   76561198056610560   0   @JAMIE@SECRET2  100 0   0   2016-01-21 10:09:32 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3   76561198056610562   0   @JAMIE@SECRET3  100 0   0   2016-01-21 10:09:35 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

**My code:**

```
connection.query('SELECT * from deposit WHERE offersent = 0;', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err){
        for (var i in rows) {
            logger.debug(rows[i])
            logger.info(rows[i].pid);
        }
    }else{
        logger.debug('SQL Error: '+ err);
    }
});
```

**The output**

```
debug:  did=1, pid=76561198056610560, oid=0, secretcode=@JAMIE@SECRET1, reward=100, status=0, offersent=0, created_at=Thu Jan 21 2016 10:09:30 GMT+0100 (CET), updated_at=0000-00-00 00:00:00
info: 76561198056610560

debug:  did=2, pid=76561198056610560, oid=0, secretcode=@JAMIE@SECRET2, reward=100, status=0, offersent=0, created_at=Thu Jan 21 2016 10:09:32 GMT+0100 (CET), updated_at=0000-00-00 00:00:00
info: 76561198056610560

debug:  did=3, pid=76561198056610560, oid=0, secretcode=@JAMIE@SECRET3, reward=100, status=0, offersent=0, created_at=Thu Jan 21 2016 10:09:35 GMT+0100 (CET), updated_at=0000-00-00 00:00:00
info: 76561198056610560
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your connection options add another field

```
supportBigNumbers: True
```

That might do it.

Refer: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thank you very much. I will accept your answer when i can.